# Issue with my custom jquery slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I'm trying to come up with a jquery slider for my personal page but I don't know how to properly get it to work, there should be a transition each 2 seconds but nothing happens!

I'm also trying to make it so that when I click the next and prev buttons it lets me browse through the slides on my own.

The container element for my custom jquery slider is index_hub_slider_container

This is my code so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = $('.index_hub_slider_item');
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].css("display", "none");
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if(slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    slides[slideIndex-1].css("display", "block");
    setTimeout(showSlides,2000);
}

});
```

```css
.index_hub_maincontainer{margin:0px 0px; width:100%; height:auto; align-items:center; background-color:#EEEEEE; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:50px 100px 25px 100px; font-family:Open Sans;}

.index_hub_tittle{width:100%; height:50px; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; color:#454545; font-family:Archivo Black; font-size:35px; font-weight:900;}

.index_hub_description{width:100%; height:50px;display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); font-size:16px; margin-bottom:40px; font-weight:200;}

.index_hub_contents_container{width:100%; height:650px; display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content:space-between; position:relative;}

.index_hub_content1{margin-top:auto; position:relative; box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); width:32%; height:40%; display:flex; background-size:cover; background-image:url('images/doggy4.jpg');}

.index_hub_content1_title{font-size:20px;  font-weight:500; text-align:center; position:absolute; bottom:10px; left:0px; z-index:99999999; color:white; text-transform:uppercase; width:100%; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); padding:8px 15px;}

.black_overlay{position:absolute; transition:all 800ms ease; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:black; opacity:0}

.black_overlay:hover{opacity:0.3;}

.black_gradient{position:absolute; transition:all 800ms ease; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)); opacity:0}

.black_gradient:hover{opacity:0.5;}

.index_hub_content2{margin-top:auto; position:relative; box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); width:32%; height:40%; display:flex; flex-flow:column-reverse; align-items:center; background-size:cover; background-image:url('images/doggy5.jpg');}

.index_hub_content2_title{font-size:20px; font-weight:500; color:white; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase; padding:8px 15px; width:100%; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:10px;}

.index_hub_content3{position:relative; box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); width:32%; height:100%; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); background-position:center; background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

.index_hub_content3_title{width:100%; font-size:20px; z-index:99999; text-align:center; font-weight:500; color:white; text-transform:uppercase; position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:10px; padding:8px 15px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);}

.index_hub_slider_container{width:66%; box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); height:56%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; overflow:hidden;}

.index_hub_slider_item{width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:0px; background-position:center; background-size:cover; /*display:none;*/}

.index_hub_slider_item_image{width:100%; height:100%; background-position:center; background-size:cover; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}

.index_hub_slider_item_texts_container{width:100%; height:20%; position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px; background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)); padding:5px 150px 5px 10px;}

.index_hub_slider_item_texts_text{font-size:13px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);}

.index_hub_slider_item_texts_link{width:auto; padding:5px 10px; background-color:var(--main_color); color:white; font-weight:500; font-size:15px; border-radius:3px; position:absolute; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); right:25px;}

.index_hub_slider_prev{position:absolute; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); left:0px; transition:all 900ms ease; opacity:0; font-size:25px; padding:8px 15px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); color:rgba(255,255,255,1.0); z-index:999999999999;}

.index_hub_slider_next{position:absolute; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); right:0px;transition:all 900ms ease; opacity:0; font-size:25px; padding:8px 15px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); color:rgba(255,255,255,1.0); z-index:99999999999;}

.index_hub_slider_container:hover .index_hub_slider_prev{opacity:1;}

.index_hub_slider_container:hover .index_hub_slider_next{opacity:1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="index_hub_maincontainer" style=" ">
    <!--<span class="index_hub_tittle" style=" ">TUS ESPECIALISTAS EN ENTRENAMIENTO CANINO</span>
    <span class="index_hub_description" style="">Disponemos de muchos planes personalizados de adiestramiento, pregúntanos que podemos hacer por ti y tu mascota</span>-->
    <div class="index_hub_contents_container" style="">
        <a class="index_hub_content1" href="/clases/domicilio" style="background-image:url('/img/dogs19.jpg');" title="Clases a domicilio" >
            <span class="index_hub_content1_title" style="" >Clases a domicilio</span>
            <div class="black_overlay" style=""></div>
        </a>
        <a class="index_hub_content2" href="/clases/grupo" style="background-image:url('/img/dogs20.jpg');" title="Clases en grupo">
            <span class="index_hub_content2_title" style="">Clases en grupo</span>
            <div class="black_overlay" style=""></div>
        </a>
        <a class="index_hub_content3" href="/formate-con-nosotros" style="background-image:url('img/dogs14.jpg'); background-position-x:55%;" title="Conviertete en adiestrador canino profesional">
            <span class="index_hub_content3_title" style="">Formate con nosotros</span>
            <div class="black_overlay" style=""></div>
        </a>
        <div class="index_hub_slider_container" href="" style="">
      <i class="index_hub_slider_prev fa fa-chevron-left pointer"></i>
   <i class="index_hub_slider_next fa fa-chevron-right pointer"></i>
            <div class="index_hub_slider_item" style="">
       <div class="index_hub_slider_item_image" style="background-image:url('/img/dogs18.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="index_hub_slider_item_texts_container" style="">
     <span class="index_hub_slider_item_texts_text" >Este es un texto descriptivo del slider que se mueve solito, o al menos espero quelo haga.</span>
                    <a class="index_hub_slider_item_texts_link" href="" style="">Leer más</a>
       </div>
      </div>
   <div class="index_hub_slider_item" style="">
       <div class="index_hub_slider_item_image" style="background-image:url('/img/dogs15.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="index_hub_slider_item_texts_container" style="">
     <span class="index_hub_slider_item_texts_text" >Este es un texto descriptivo del slider que se mueve solito, o al menos espero quelo haga.</span>
                    <a class="index_hub_slider_item_texts_link" href="" style="">Leer más</a>
       </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also just noticed it's giving an error slides[i].css is not a function, why is that?

Comment: change `[i]` to `eq(i)`.  Bracket notation on a jQuery object returns the underlying dom element, not a jQuery object, which is required for the `css()` call

Comment: However you don't need that loop.  Just call css on the slides and jQuery will do the iteration itself under the hood.

Comment: Ca you elaborate on that? also, I changed it to eq(i) but it still doesn't work

Comment: on how jquery will be looping under the hood

Comment: When you perform a jQuery lookup, such as $(selector), the result is a jQuery object that contains a stack which holds all the elements that were found.  The majority of methods jQuery offers that operates off of themselves like this, automatically apply the operation to all the elements in the result stack.  So methods like css() to change css, or on() to create new event bindings, can be done on the jQuery object itself, without having to iterate over the stack yourself, as jQuery does it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var slideIndex = 0;
  showSlides();

  function showSlides() {
    //get the slides, and hide all of them
    //jQuery will iterate over all of the elements
    //in the result stack
    var slides = $('.index_hub_slider_item').hide();
    //show the current slide
    //++ after the variable will increment it after
    //it is used
    slides.eq(slideIndex++).css("display", "block");
    //if the slide index is equal to or greater than
    //the array length (size of n = indexes of 0-(n-1))
    //set it back to 0
    if (slideIndex >= slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 0
    }
    //start the next iteration
    setTimeout(showSlides,2000);
}

});
```

```css
.index_hub_maincontainer{margin:0px 0px; width:100%; height:auto; align-items:center; background-color:#EEEEEE; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:50px 100px 25px 100px; font-family:Open Sans;}

.index_hub_tittle{width:100%; height:50px; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; color:#454545; font-family:Archivo Black; font-size:35px; font-weight:900;}

.index_hub_description{width:100%; height:50px;display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); font-size:16px; margin-bottom:40px; font-weight:200;}

.index_hub_contents_container{width:100%; height:650px; display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content:space-between; position:relative;}

.index_hub_content1{margin-top:auto; position:relative; box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); width:32%; height:40%; display:flex; background-size:cover; background-image:url('images/doggy4.jpg');}

.index_hub_content1_title{font-size:20px;  font-weight:500; text-align:center; position:absolute; bottom:10px; left:0px; z-index:99999999; color:white; text-transform:uppercase; width:100%; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); padding:8px 15px;}

.black_overlay{position:absolute; transition:all 800ms ease; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:black; opacity:0}

.black_overlay:hover{opacity:0.3;}

.black_gradient{position:absolute; transition:all 800ms ease; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)); opacity:0}

.black_gradient:hover{opacity:0.5;}

.index_hub_content2{margin-top:auto; position:relative; box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); width:32%; height:40%; display:flex; flex-flow:column-reverse; align-items:center; background-size:cover; background-image:url('images/doggy5.jpg');}

.index_hub_content2_title{font-size:20px; font-weight:500; color:white; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase; padding:8px 15px; width:100%; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:10px;}

.index_hub_content3{position:relative; box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); width:32%; height:100%; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); background-position:center; background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

.index_hub_content3_title{width:100%; font-size:20px; z-index:99999; text-align:center; font-weight:500; color:white; text-transform:uppercase; position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:10px; padding:8px 15px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);}

.index_hub_slider_container{width:66%; box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); height:56%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; overflow:hidden;}

.index_hub_slider_item{width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:0px; background-position:center; background-size:cover; /*display:none;*/}

.index_hub_slider_item_image{width:100%; height:100%; background-position:center; background-size:cover; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}

.index_hub_slider_item_texts_container{width:100%; height:20%; position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px; background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)); padding:5px 150px 5px 10px;}

.index_hub_slider_item_texts_text{font-size:13px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);}

.index_hub_slider_item_texts_link{width:auto; padding:5px 10px; background-color:var(--main_color); color:white; font-weight:500; font-size:15px; border-radius:3px; position:absolute; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); right:25px;}

.index_hub_slider_prev{position:absolute; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); left:0px; transition:all 900ms ease; opacity:0; font-size:25px; padding:8px 15px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); color:rgba(255,255,255,1.0); z-index:999999999999;}

.index_hub_slider_next{position:absolute; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); right:0px;transition:all 900ms ease; opacity:0; font-size:25px; padding:8px 15px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); color:rgba(255,255,255,1.0); z-index:99999999999;}

.index_hub_slider_container:hover .index_hub_slider_prev{opacity:1;}

.index_hub_slider_container:hover .index_hub_slider_next{opacity:1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="index_hub_maincontainer" style=" ">
    <!--<span class="index_hub_tittle" style=" ">TUS ESPECIALISTAS EN ENTRENAMIENTO CANINO</span>
    <span class="index_hub_description" style="">Disponemos de muchos planes personalizados de adiestramiento, pregúntanos que podemos hacer por ti y tu mascota</span>-->
    <div class="index_hub_contents_container" style="">
        <a class="index_hub_content1" href="/clases/domicilio" style="background-image:url('/img/dogs19.jpg');" title="Clases a domicilio" >
            <span class="index_hub_content1_title" style="" >Clases a domicilio</span>
            <div class="black_overlay" style=""></div>
        </a>
        <a class="index_hub_content2" href="/clases/grupo" style="background-image:url('/img/dogs20.jpg');" title="Clases en grupo">
            <span class="index_hub_content2_title" style="">Clases en grupo</span>
            <div class="black_overlay" style=""></div>
        </a>
        <a class="index_hub_content3" href="/formate-con-nosotros" style="background-image:url('img/dogs14.jpg'); background-position-x:55%;" title="Conviertete en adiestrador canino profesional">
            <span class="index_hub_content3_title" style="">Formate con nosotros</span>
            <div class="black_overlay" style=""></div>
        </a>
        <div class="index_hub_slider_container" href="" style="">
      <i class="index_hub_slider_prev fa fa-chevron-left pointer"></i>
   <i class="index_hub_slider_next fa fa-chevron-right pointer"></i>
            <div class="index_hub_slider_item" style="">
       <div class="index_hub_slider_item_image" style="background-image:url('/img/dogs18.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="index_hub_slider_item_texts_container" style="">
     <span class="index_hub_slider_item_texts_text" >1Este es un texto descriptivo del slider que se mueve solito, o al menos espero quelo haga.</span>
                    <a class="index_hub_slider_item_texts_link" href="" style="">Leer más</a>
       </div>
      </div>
   <div class="index_hub_slider_item" style="">
       <div class="index_hub_slider_item_image" style="background-image:url('/img/dogs15.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="index_hub_slider_item_texts_container" style="">
     <span class="index_hub_slider_item_texts_text" >2Este es un texto descriptivo del slider que se mueve solito, o al menos espero quelo haga.</span>
                    <a class="index_hub_slider_item_texts_link" href="" style="">Leer más</a>
       </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```